# Genatragted MySQL table name by Hibernate is different

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am generating MySQL table by Hibernate as follows:-

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "buyerPartyDetails")
    public class BuyerPartyDetails { 
    .......      
    }
```

But in MySQL the actual table name is as  **buyerpartydetails** I was expecting it should be **buyerPartyDetails**. How do I force hibernte to genarate table name as my espection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force Hibernate to quote the identifiers by setting:

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

or

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions=true
```

which will generate quoted table names in DDL. It might however require `SET GLOBAL SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;` as by default MySQL uses backticks  ` to quote the names.

Comment: I am not generating the table by DDL. I am generating by Hibernate/persistence @Entity as given above. I set the property of Hibernate hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true and hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions=true. But it has no effect all. So it is not working for me.